# <html /> element is only taking up half the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image: img]

I am working on a React web page and I tried to see what the site looks like on mobile, so I switched to mobile view, and as you can see my  element is only taking up half of the screen, so my content and my navbar and all my elements are actually only on half of the screen.

Here is my index.css

```
html {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #ececec;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The table that you can see has a `min-width` attribute, so it can actually be seen, but its container div is also the same size as the html tag... Help!!

I noticed that the html element width is always as big as the screen of the device is, and it gets "stuck" at that point.. If I create a screen size that is 400px wide, the  tag is 400px wide, and instead of wrapping all the content it's just a fixed width of 400px...

I added a `min-width: 1000px` to my `#root` and it looks okay now but my html width is still the same as my screen width which I think should not be like that

Comment: `<html>` element is a block element so by default it takes 100% of the width.

Comment: @JMadelaine Okay but why is it not 100% in my case then??

Comment: Are you zooming out in the mobile view? It looks as though your mobile screen is the same size as your html element, but your table stretches past the borders of the mobile screen.

Comment: What value does your table have for `min-width`? Try setting it to something small like `20px` and see if this fixes your `html` element issue.

Comment: @JMadelaine Yes it is zoomed out, I removed the `min-width` property and that forced the table inside the html element, but my navbar is still outside the html tag...

Comment: Show us the HTML and other relevant CSS - not a screen shot. Without it, we are just guessing.

Comment: @disinfor I added some more info please check my OP

Comment: Your navbar must have a `min-width` property set too. Your html element is working correctly, it is 100% of the screen width, but your navbar element is **wider** than the screen width because you are setting a `min-width` property on it. Remove the `min-width` property, and if you need to, change the contents of your navbar so everything is visible within the phone screen.

Comment: @randomboiguyhere that is not enough information. You keep mentioning a `table`. Post your HTML and CSS for this. We are still in the dark. If someone came to you for help and gave you the information you gave us, with no other context, could you help them? The answer is no, you would also be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can find more info about this here:
[Responsive Meta Tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width as `100vw`, not `100%` and if this won't work, set `min-width` to `100vw`, too

Comment: This should be a comment, as we have no idea what the actual code looks like and you are just guessing.